# Django queue function calls

Tags: python, django, post, dhtmlx

I have small problem with the nature of the data processing and django.
for starters. I have webpage with advanced dhtmlx table. While adding rows to table DHTMLX automatically send POST data to mine django backend where this is processed and return XML data is sent to webpage. All of it works just fine when adding 1 row at a time. But when adding several rows at a time, some problem starts to occur. For starters, I have checked the order of send data to backend and its proper (let say Rows ID 1,2,3,4 are sent in that order). Problem is that backend processes the query when it arrives, usually they arrives in the same order (even though the randomness of the Internet). But django fires the same function for them instantly and it's complex functions that takes some time to compute, then sends the response. Problem is that every time function is called there is a change in the database and one of the variables depends on how big is a database table we are altering. While having the same data table altered in wrong order (different threads speed) the result data is rubbish.

Is there any automatic solution to queue calls of one web called function so that every call could go to the queue and wait for previous to complete ??
I want to make such a queue for this function only.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should build the queue in django. If the rows need to be processed serially on the backend, then insert the change data into a queue and process the queue like an event handler.

You could build a send queue using dhtmlx's event handlers and the ajax callback handler, yet why?  The network is already slow, slowing it down further is the wrong approach.

Comment: Well You are right. When I thought about it more, there is a problem of javascript being single threaded and python multi. Synchronization between table and backend with wildness of the Internet connection. To much work, to much errors, to much data sent in between, it's easier to generate whole table in django from scratch after it's update than send it to frontend in xml rather than syncing the two. It's super easy and lighter, but it's just skipping the problem instead of solving it :/